# Continuous proof question

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let f : [0, ∞) → R be a continuous function and let g : [0, ∞) → R be the function
defined by
g(x) = sup{f(y) | y ∈ [0, x]}.
Prove that g is also continuous.

I tried using the Intro to Real Analysis text to complete this proof but I am unsure of how to manipulate the supermum.
I know that I need to show that g is increasing, but then I do not know where to go from there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prove the contrapositive: if $g$ is discontinuous at $x_0$, then so is $f$. Indeed, showing $g$ is increasing is of great help because discontinuities in increasing functions need to be jump discontinuities. In particular (with the exception of the special case $x_0 = 0$) we must have
$$\lim_{x \to x_0^-} g(x) < \lim_{x \to x_0^+} g(x).$$
These one-sided limits exist essentially by the continuous version of the monotone convergence theorem. From the left, the function is increasing and bounded above by $g(x_0 + 1)$. From the right, the function is decreasing, bounded below by $g(x_0/2)$ (I didn't choose $x_0 - 1$, just in case $x_0 \in (0, 1)$).

On the other hand if $x_0 = 0$, then the only way that we can have a discontinuity is if
$$f(0) = g(0) < \lim_{x \to 0^-} g(0).$$
This needs to be dealt with as a separate case.

If $x_0 > 0$, then let the left limit of $g$ be $L$ and the right limit be $R$. I would suggest proving that $f(x) \le L$ for all $x \in [0, x_0]$, implying that $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) \le L$ if such a limit exists. But, on the other hand, for any $n \in \Bbb{N}$, there must exist some $x_n \in [0, x_0 + 1/n]$ such that $f(x_n) \ge R$. This implies that $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) \ge R$ if it exists. Thus, the limit cannot exist, hence $f$ cannot be continuous at $x_0$.

I'll leave the $x_0 = 0$ case to you, as well as filling in the blanks! Let me know if you need more help.